# Convert isapi rewrite rules to IIS 7 rewrite

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I am using helicon isapi rewrite with vbSEO on vBulletin forums.  I don't see any need to be using a separate isapi rewrite tool if I'm using IIS 7.  Rewrite rules and regex are not my strength.  If anyone can help me convert the info below into an IIS 7 url rewrite configuration I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*vbdotnetforums.com
RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*vbdotnetforums.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(admincp/|modcp/|cron)
RewriteRule ^/((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ /vbseo.php?vbseourl=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*vbdotnetforums.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images|search\.php|api\.php)/
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /vbseo.php?vbseourl=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^((urllist|sitemap).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*vbdotnetforums.com"  />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*vbdotnetforums.com" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/(admincp/|modcp/|cron)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/vbseo.php?vbseourl={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*vbdotnetforums.com" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^/(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images|search\.php|api\.php)/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/vbseo.php?vbseourl={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Did you know that you can import ISAPI_Rewrite rules (which are based on `mod_rewrite`) using IIS7's management console?

[image]