# Blocking invalid URL and redirect to homepage in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, dns

Currently I am using the web hosting service provided by another company. It uses IIS 7/IIS 8 and allows customers to modify `web.config` according to their needs.

Suppose I have set up two valid URL:

1. http://www.example.com
2. http://dev.example.com

Now, when I try to access `http://abc.example.com`, `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden` is returned; and if I then try to access `http://www.example.com/abc`, `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` is returned.

How can I configure `web.config` such that users will be redirected to `http://www.example.com` when they are trying to access an invalid URL?

I have tried to use the snippet provided by the company but without success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
             </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have a look here, maybe this can help you further [Convert isapi rewrite rules to IIS 7 rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038145/convert-isapi-rewrite-rules-to-iis-7-rewrite)

Comment: Sorry, after reading the question, I am still unable to set up a correct configuration for my case.

Comment: does your provider support ISAPI? Maybe you could try using ISAPI rules in order to redirect unexisting urls to your homepage: [ISAPI DOCS](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wObqULbm5g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In system.web in webconfig tag add this tag

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Index"> 
 </customErrors>
```

This will redirect you to the home page whenever an error occured
You can be more specific with redirection by adding in customErrors tag

```
<error statusCode="401" redirect="/error/otherpage"/>
```

This will indicate the page that you will be redirected to when 401 error occurs

Comment: I have just tried `<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://www.example.com" mode="On"></customErrors>` without success. `403` is still returned when I access an invalid URL. Any clue?

Comment: This solution works if the invalid url begin with http://www.example.com because it does the redirection in the same application which is hosted in an IIS site so in the defaultredirection you must sfecify the local path